# Check if user exists in database error

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I'm really new to php and been following a tutorial on youtube by php academy. Basically it's a script(s) that allows for login,registering and a remember me option, the tutorial is 2 years old so I tried to change some of the mysql functions to mysqli but I'm running into some problems..when I enter a username and hit login I get a **"mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in user.php line 9"** error and my if statement says **"cannot find username try registering"** but it should show "exists" because the username I entered is in fact in the database..I'm puzzled, also please forgive me if the script isn't the most secure, I know things should be escaped and such, your help would be appreciated

**User.php :**

```
<?php

function user_exists($username)
{

$username=$username;
$query = ("SELECT count(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$username'");

    if(mysql_num_rows($query)===1)
    {return true;

    } else{
        return false;
    }


}




?>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php

    include ('core/init.php');


    if(user_exists('drellen')===true){
        echo "exists";

    }

    if(empty($_POST)===false){
        $username=$_POST['username'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];

        if(empty($username) === true|| empty($password)=== true)

        {

            echo $error[]="Enter a username and password";

        } 
            else if (user_exists($username)===false) 

            {
            echo $error[]="Cannot find username try registering";
            }




    }
```

please note that the init.php has users.php included in it***** 
Might have a mixture of the old mysql and the new mysqli functions mixed in, help making it full mysqli would be appreciated

Comment: did you actually run the query? Num rows just counts the rows returned, it doesn't run the query.

Comment: In the tutorial he used mysql_result($query,0)==1) ? true : false to see if a row with that queried user name existed and I thought mysql_num_row($query) was the mysqli equivalent sorry, should I have used mysql_result($query)? And yes I checked the query in phpMyadmin

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252904/how-to-check-if-a-row-exists-in-mysql-i-e-check-if-an-email-exists-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

You have not used `mysql_query()` to run query. How you get number of rows without it.

Note -> You should use `mysqli_*` functions instead of `mysql_*`

```
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT count(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$username'");
//$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
```

Comment: Suggest updating the answer to help the OP in converting to the use of mysqli instead of mysql functions.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
function user_exists($username)
{
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$username' LIMIT 1 ") or die(mysql_error());
    if($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Note :** `mysql_*`  is deprecated. use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

**UPDATE 2:**

```
    function user_exists($username)
    {
        global $your_db_conn;
        $sql = "SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$username' LIMIT 1 ";
        $result = mysql_query($sql, $your_db_conn) or die(mysql_error());
        if($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks< I tried this and an error came up about using PDO or mysqli as expected but the die error says: No databse selcted, but I selected it when setting up my connection.php script

Comment: its not found your database connectivity.

Comment: Just double checked my connection.php script and it doesn't show an error which I'd like to assume it connected to the correct database?

Comment: use the connection variable in function in sql like my update 2

Comment: I was still getting a error so I searched a bit and found that if($result -> num_rows) worked when drellen is in the username variable the if statement echoes "exists" but now when I change it to 'billy' which isn't in the database it still echoes exists

Answer (score -2):

Here is a working example

After doing some digging around i found that the most important part in this new function is calling the **global $db**, and for sanitizing adding the `$db, $data` as well as in the query. if you look up other basic exampels of using `mysqli_query($db, $sql);` you will catch onto this quite easily

```
<?php
    
    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'database');

    function sanitize($data) {
        global $db;
        return mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $data);
    }

    function user_exists($username)
    {
        global $db;
        $username = sanitize($username);
        $sql = "SELECT `id` FROM `Users` WHERE `username`='$username' LIMIT 1";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die('query');
        if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

?>
<h1>test</h1>

<?php



if (user_exists('admin') === true){
 echo "Good news, this exists";
} else {
    echo "no good";
}

?>
```