# QUERY AND ECHO Data INTO HTML INPUT fields

Tags: php, mysql

I've written a script that in short is supposed to query data from the database and echo a result into a HTML form field. However, I have been unsuccessful. Please see code below:

```
<?php


include("dbconfig.php");

$val = '6';

$result = mysqli_query("Select * from test where testid= '$val'");
$name = (mysqli_num_rows($result)==1) ? mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) : null;

if(is_array($name)){


?>

<html>

<body>

<form>
Name: <input type="text" id="firstname" value="<?php echo $name['firstname']; ?>"/>
</form>

<?php
} else {

echo "No such name exists";


}

?>



</body>
</html>
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong. Because it won't echo anything into the field and I find it rather annoying because majority of the scripts I've come across are quite similar to this one.

Help will be much appreciated.

Thank You,

Sohail.

Comment: To be clear, the intended result here (if it was successful) would be: `Name: <input type="text" id="firstname" value="6"/>`

Comment: There could be a number of problems with your code. You might want to explain what happens when you run it for easier debugging. You could also dump some variables with var_dump($var). I can see that you are testing if mysqli_num_rows() equals one. This should be a "greater or equal" comparison, I think.

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake... that was supposed to say "where testid = '$val''

Comment: If you change that in your test code, does it work?

Comment: When I run the query, it echoes 'No such name exists'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested the below and it works OK. @Fred-ii- gave you loads of good info, especially using error debugging - but you do need to supply the connection object which you were missing.

```
<?php
    error_reporting( E_ALL );

    include("conn.php");

    $val = 6;

    /* What is the name of the $connection object ? */
    $result = mysqli_query( $conn, "Select * from `test` where `testid`='$val'" );
    $name=( $result ) ? mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) : false;

?>  
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Ya gotta have a title...</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            if( !empty( $name ) ){
                echo "
                    <form>
                        Name: <input type='text' id='firstname' value='{$name['firstname']}'/>
                    </form>";
            } else {
                echo "No such name exists";
            }
        ?>
    </
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution worked nicely. I did have to make some alterations to my database connection file as that was written as a php data object connection and not in mysqli format. But we're all good!

Answer (score 0):

You did not pass your db connection to your query, so it never gets executed.

- Assuming a successful connection using `mysqli_`

This line of code:

```
$result = mysqli_query("Select * from test where testid= '$val'");
```

needs to have a connection parameter:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection, "Select * from test where testid= '$val'");
```

and is unknown to us as to which MySQL API you're using to connect with.

Your query may have failed, so check for errors.

```
$result = mysqli_query("Select * from test where testid= '$val'")
    or die(mysqli_error($connection));
```

and replacing the `$connection` variable with the one that you have assigned in your `dbconfig.php` which is unknown to us.

Different MySQL APIs/functions do not intermix.

Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

You're also open to an SQL injection. Use a prepared statement.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

If you want to check if a row exists, see my other answer on Stack:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/22253579/1415724

Comment: @MuhammadSohailArif *"does not work"* isn't much to go on really. check for errors, your query may have failed. I also included a link to one of my answers I gave for another question, which is at the bottom of my answer (in an edit).  http://stackoverflow.com/a/22253579/1415724 you can't go wrong with that. Anyway, check for errors. Use error reporting also. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php