# $_POST creates Array, but leaves out Value data if it contains a comma

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

Currently I am creating a dynamic site that uses check boxes to gather information. The problem is, when the value of a checkbox contains a comma, the remaining text after the "," is dropped from the array.

In Essence:

```
if (isset($_POST['team_members'])){
        $team_members = $_POST['team_members'];
        if (is_array($team_members)){
        $team_members = implode("|", $team_members);
        }
```

team_members data includes:

```
<input type="Checkbox" name="team_members[]" value="Company Name 1">
<input type="Checkbox" name="team_members[]" value="Company Name 2">
<input type="Checkbox" name="team_members[]" value="Company Name 3, Inc.">
<input type="Checkbox" name="team_members[]" value="Company Name 4, LLC.">
```

Let's say that I chose [0] and [1],
$team_members becomes: "Company Name 1|Company Name 2"

If I chose [0] and [2]
$team_members becomes: "Company Name 1|Company Name 3,"

Any help will be appreciated.

edit: Array ( [0] => Accenture [1] => Alion [2] => CACI [3] => Deloitte, )
It appears it is also removing things by "space" and not ","...

Comment: Right below `if (isset($_POST['team_members'])){`, do `print_r($_POST['team_members'])`, and post the output please.

Comment: are you sure [2] posted completely ? echo [2] and make sure its print `'Company Name 3, Inc.'`

Comment: Is this being submitted by standard form submit of type post? Not any javascript meddling in the works?

Comment: Array ( [0] => Accenture [1] => Alion [2] => CACI [3] => Deloitte, )

Comment: Are your values _actually_ quoted in your code?  They are in your post. Seems like this error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29901488/html-input-form-box-not-populating-php-value-after-first-space  Your question may be closed as "Off-topic: Why isn't my code working..." if you do not reply to all requests for additional details.

Comment: <input type=checkbox name=team_members[]". " value=" . $row3["company"] . ">" . $row3["company"];

Comment: Yup, improper quoting.  This is a duplicate.  Next time you ask a question, copy paste your real code so that everything is clear and accurate for us.

Comment: Can I use a mixture of " and ' when im quoting withing a quote?

Comment: Yes or `\"` to escape double quotes

Comment: echo "<td><input type=checkbox name='team_members[]' value=" . $row3["company"] . ">" . $row3["company"]; 

Should look like this?

echo "<td><input type=checkbox name=/"team_members[]" value=" . $row3["company"] . ">" . $row3["company"];   ?

Comment: ok got it. thanks! You guys are awesome!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML input form box not populating PHP value after first space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29901488/html-input-form-box-not-populating-php-value-after-first-space)

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be the issue. I just cant find a way to place value in quotations without breaking the php output code...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33526632/2943403