# How do I connect to a MySQLi db using PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am creating a login form and am having trouble with it not successfully logging in. My form looks like this

```
<form method="post" action="phpScripts/loginProcess.php">

    <input type="text" name="uname" value="" placeholder="Username">

    <input type="password" name="pass" value="" placeholder="Password">

    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit">

</form>
```

I have already checked and I am connecting to the database, and my uname and pass are both correct. I have double checked plenty of times. The issue is within my query. Here is the loginProcess.php file

```
<?php

    require_once ('dbconn.php');



    if(isset($_POST['login'])){

        $uname  = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['uname']);
        $pass   = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);

        $query  = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM staff WHERE uname='$uname'");
        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

        if ($numrows !=0){
            die("Success!!");
        }
        else{
            die("That user doesnt exist");
        }

    }
    else{
        echo "Username or Password incorrect";
    }
?>
```

With the help of [Fred-ii-](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1415724/fred-ii) I was able to figure out my mistakes and really quickly fix my login issue! I wanted to supply the code I used to login in case anyone else came across this problem.

Here is the code that I am using to login. I feel as I can make it a little less redundant with the execute and $userSql/$pwSql. Any suggestions to clean this up would be greatly appreciated!

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);


require_once ('dbconn.php');


$uname = $_POST['uname'];
$pass  = $_POST['pass'];

$userSql   = "SELECT * FROM staff WHERE uname=:uname";
$getUser = $conn->prepare($userSql);
$getUser->execute(array(
    ':uname' => $uname
));


if($getUser->rowCount()){    
    $pwSql = "SELECT pass FROM staff WHERE uname =:uname";
    $getPw = $conn->prepare($pwSql);
    $getPw->execute(array(
        ':uname' => $uname
    ));
    $pw = implode($getPw->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

    if(password_verify($pass,$pw)){
        header("Location: ../../staffHome.php");
    }else{
        echo "Oops! You have entered in an incorrect password!";
    }

}else{
    echo "Oops! That user doesn't exist!";
}
?>
```

Comment: Which of the 3 message do you see after submitting the form?

Comment: you have many errors here. Once you get this going `if(isset($_POST['login'])){...}` you'll be faced with other brick walls. Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code. Because this will NEVER happen `if(isset($_POST['login'])){...}` since and without JS, forms do not hold the name attribute. But you're probably using JS but not showing us.

Comment: @sebastianForsberg I am getting the 3rd. The "Username or Password incorrect"

Comment: Then you need to read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php

Comment: @Fred-ii- I am not using any JS.

Comment: @CTrujillo I have posted my answer for you below. I believe I have given you enough in there to get you going.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks again. I was able to figure out a solution by skimming through everything you supplied me with. I am now going to focus on the security portion and check out the password hashing and XSS that you mentioned as well. I provided an edit and showed what I found to work for me. If you can take a look and see if there is anything you can recommend I would appreciate it. I cannot thank you enough, you have been extremely helpful!

Comment: @CTrujillo You're welcome. Looks good to me. Remember to use that password hashing I mentioned. Other than that, you're good to go ;-) just don't go LIVE yet if you're using plain text passwords, because hackers can easily "hack" into your db. *Stay safe!*

Comment: @Fred-ii- Hey sorry to bug, but I have updated the code once more to include hashed passwords. I used the password_hash() to create the hashed password in case that it wasn't clear from what I supplied. I feel like the code could be more "dry" tho? any suggestions on how to clean it up? Am I still vulnerable to any XSS or brute attacks? After double checking your comments and the resources I believe that I am in the clear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the scoop.

Your conditional statement `if(isset($_POST['login'])){...}` will never happen, since forms do not hold the name attribute (unless you were using JS/jQuery). You need to name your submit that.  `<input name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" value="submit">`, as PHP does not rely on "id", it relies on a "name" attribute (or again, if you were using JS/jQuery, but that isn't the case here). Then **remove** `name="login"` from `<form>`.

Then you're not passing the connection to your escape function.

Then you're mixing `mysql_` functions that to not intermix with anything other than that, `mysql_`.

We also don't know which MySQL API you're using to connect with.

So, use the same one from connecting to querying, Use either `mysqli_` or PDO and preferably using a prepared statement.

**Edit:** comment from the OP: *"I am using PDO to connect."*

- You must use the same one from connecting to querying. You can't mix `mysql_` or `mysqli_` with PDO.

Consult:

- [Can I mix MySQL APIs in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php)
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php
- PDO error handling http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

**Passwords**

I also noticed that you may be storing passwords in plain text. This is not recommended.

Use one of the following:

- [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471)
- [`crypt()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)
- [`bcrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt)
- [`scrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt)
- [**On OPENWALL**](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)
- [**PBKDF2**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)
- [**PBKDF2 on PHP.net**](http://php.net/hash-pbkdf2)
- PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.
- Compatibility pack (if PHP < 5.5) https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/

Other links:

- [**PBKDF2 For PHP**](https://defuse.ca/php-pbkdf2.htm)

---

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**`mysqli_*` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

Comment: I am using PDO to connect. Sorry I should have mentioned that. You have given me a lot to read up on, thank you! I will read through that you have supplied me with and update this once I have something to update.

Comment: @RamRaider thanks ;-)

Comment: @CTrujillo ah there you go and I did write that in my answer that you can't mix MySQL APIs. You must use the same one from connecting to querying. You can't mix `mysql_` or `mysqli_` with PDO. and you're welcome.

Comment: @CTrujillo You can also consult one of my answers http://stackoverflow.com/a/22253579/1415724 where it does contain a PDO method to check if a row exists. I'm sure you will make use of that also and to get it to work for what you want to do.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yea I didn't realize that I couldn't mix them. I am under the impression that PDO is a little more beginner friendly? is this wrong? What would the pros/cons be of using mysqli over pdo and vice versa?

Comment: @CTrujillo it's somewhat of a preferential method really. Some things in mysqli with prepared statements that can't be done in PDO and vice-versa. But, the important thing here is to use a prepared statement for either one, and using a safe password hashing function.

Comment: @CTrujillo another thing to remember if you're going to use `password_hash()` or the compat pack (as per the links in my answer and to which I hope you do if you're going live with this), is that your password column will need to be long enough to accomodate the hash. Minimum length should be 60, but PHP.net recommends 255 (varchar). As per the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: Always quality answers sir!

Comment: @Darren Thanks Darren. *Happy New Year* btw ;-) cheers

Comment: @CTrujillo I believe I have answered the question and the question should be closed, otherwise others may be tempted to post more answers. One of which was posted other than my own, but that is wrong for too many reasons. If you can mark my answer, great. Otherwise, your question will remain in the unanswered category.

Comment: You are right, and I selected your answer thanks again! If I need to do something else let me know. I am still learning how SO works as well.

Comment: @CTrujillo All is good ;-) *Happy New Year* and coding :-) *Cheers*