# Check submit form input with mysqli database

Tags: php, html, mysqli

When I type a code into my form I want my PHP code to check on submit that the code exists in the database and then run MySqli query. I have tried to do that but I get error `Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)` I have Googled the problem but not a single one did help me to solve or understand my problem.

FORM

```
<p><b>Skriv in din laddkod nedan och tryck på "Ladda"</b></p>
<form action="laddaklar.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="laddkod"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Ladda" />
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php 

session_start();

    $mysqli = NEW MySQLI ('localhost', 'root', '', 'ph');

    $laddkod = isset($_POST['laddkod']) ? $_POST['laddkod'] : '';



    $kod= "SELECT refill from card_refill"; 
    $result = $mysqli->query($kod);


    if(isset($_POST['submit'] && $laddkod==$result)){


     $resultSet = $mysqli->query ("UPDATE card_credit SET value= value + (select credit from card_refill WHERE refill='" . $_POST['laddkod'] . "') WHERE card_id = '" . $_SESSION['card'] . "' ");

 echo "<b>Ditt kort har laddats!</b>";
}
else
{
    echo "Fel laddkod";
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't be `if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $laddkod==$result){` ? isset not closed correctly!!

Comment: can you tell us what it is you want to do here exactly? even with the syntax error, your code makes no sense.

Comment: The reason why the mysql library was depreciated in PHP was because of the easy mysql injection, when I see this code I see now that mysqli has made no difference and this is going to start all over again. I would recommend usind PDO instead.

Comment: @Xorifelse the use of PDO alone does not safeguard against a possible SQL injection; a prepared statement does and mysqli_ does have that option to use it also. ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I know it does, but PDO forces someone to code object orientated which hopefully making somebody more aware of these things.

Comment: @Xorifelse depending on their PHP version, they may not have access to PDO through the MySQL library, but through PostgreSQL. But yeah, PDO's nice to work with.

Comment: So, I take it we're talking amongst ourselves here. Had [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34774626/check-submit-form-input-with-mysqli-database#comment57294304_34774626) been answered, maybe this would have expedited things here. Do feel free to join in here at anytime, *don't be shy*. ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have tried as JayBlanchard suggested. But without any progress. I've double-checked so that a query is correct and it is. What I want to do is type a code in the form and then check if exists in the database and if it does exist load that account with money.

Comment: had I known that in the first place, I'd of answered this within 30 seconds of your initial post. But my comment was never replied to, so I have moved on.

Comment: I'm sorry @Fred-ii- im tryind to find answears, undersand and learn. I'm sorry :(

Comment: what you need to do here is to check if a row exists bearing the values you're looking to match against. Consult my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/22253579/ it shows you how to do this and you can base yourself on that model to get you started, *good luck*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error that you're getting:

> Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression

Is caused by what looks like an attempt to use an expression here:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'] && $laddkod==$result)){...
```

You have to close the `isset()` properly and remove the spurious extra `)`:

```
if( isset($_POST['submit']) && $laddkod==$row['refill'] ){...
-----------------------add^  --------------------remove^
```

Furthermore you're not fetching any row results for the first query:

```
$kod= "SELECT refill from card_refill"; 
$result = $mysqli->query($kod);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc(); // The value will be in the $row array
```

Then you appear to never execute the `UPDATE` query.

---

Additionally it is not clear where you're setting `$_SESSION['card']`, but you will want to make sure it is set before attempting the `UPDATE` query.

Comment: Nicely spotted, I looked over it :)

Comment: @JayBlanchard Thanks alot that did it and it dosent show the error now. But it dosent check if $laddkod=$kod. It just give my output that the right code is wrong. What could be the problem?

Comment: `$result` in your line of code is either false (failed query) or a `resultset` which would never compare with a `string`. You'd first have to fetch a row from the `resultset` in order to get the data you want.

Comment: You have to fetch the value from `$result` using something like [`fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

Comment: @JayBlanchard I have now tried as you suggested but without any progress. I've double-checked so that a query is correct and it is.

Comment: What is in the `$row` array @Fredrik?

Comment: What i understand the `$row` should have the existing `refill` code in the database?

Comment: It should, but you should spit it out to make sure. `print_r($row);`

Comment: it prints out `Array ( [refill] => refill500 ) 1`, whatever i type. `refill500` does exists. In `card_refill` i have 2 refill codes `refill500` and also `refill100` @JayBlanchard

Comment: So you will need to compare like this `$laddkod==$row['refill']` @Fredrik. See my edited answer above.

Comment: You are awesome. Your answear worked :D Thanks a lot :D