# Checking if Email exist in Database

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to check if an email address exist in the database after typing the email on the form

here is my code

```
$emailbox = $_POST['loginemailbox'];
$check_email =mysqli_query(" SELECT * FROM Registration WHERE Email = '$emailbox'"); 

if(mysqli_num_rows($check_email) == 1)
  {
      echo $emailbox." is found in the database :)";
  } else 
  {
    echo $emailbox."is not found in database :(";
   }
```

what am i doing wrong here , can anyone point out to me the error

Comment: the obvious error would be the missing mysqli connection on the `mysqli_query` function argument, but since you're using mysqli, why not use prepared statements instead

Comment: where is database connection?

Comment: Is it possible that the email does not exist in the database?

Comment: Below @Frayne Konok is right :)

Comment: the email exist in the db

Comment: check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36299740/checking-if-email-exist-in-database/36299830#36299830) now, I added a sqlfiddle for you with example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a row exists in MySQL? (i.e. check if an email exists in MySQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252904/how-to-check-if-a-row-exists-in-mysql-i-e-check-if-an-email-exists-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

> Note: PDO is best for query. As you are using `mysqli` so here you
>   have to use a prepare statement for best performance and good/ smart
>   look. I answer your question just like you are doing.

Make a database connection, use it in the query.

**Try something like this:**

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// Perform queries
$check_email = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Registration WHERE Email = '$emailbox'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($check_email)){
    echo $emailbox." is found in the database :)";
}else{
  echo $emailbox."is not found in database :(";
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

**Output**

The output is from a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72e65/2)

Comment: i added the connection in the code and it still did not work
it say the the email is not the the database

Comment: if your email is not in database then the message must show, check the `table name` and `field name`.

Comment: i just recheck the field name in the db and they are correct; idk what is the problem

Comment: can you please make a sqlfiddle so that we can test it.

Comment: @slim, check the answer again, i added a link of sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing `mysqli_query($connection, $query)`
Try :

```
$connection = mysqli_connect('hostname','db_user','db_pass','db_name');
$check_email = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM Registration WHERE Email = '$emailbox'");
```

For more detail : [Mysqli_Query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Answer (score 0):

if you have checked after

1.adding the connection in the code

2.check table name and field name

the Please Check for

1.space before and after the email saved in database.

2.trim the email you are posting... trim($emailbox)