# Can't get my data Inserted into MySQL database, using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am working on a school project and can't get registration page done right. It just doesn't insert the data in table.

[Here is a screenshot for database and table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJhZv.png)

I have added the HTML, and after going through all your answers I think I am using outdated videos and study material to learn (PHP, HTML, CSS, Website Security).

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Register</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="form">
      <h2>Registeration</h2>
      <form action="" method="post">
              Name<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="First & Last name" required><br><br>
              Username<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"required><br><br>
              Password<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Keep it Strong"required><br><br>
              Confirm Password<input type="password" name="confirm-pass" placeholder="Re-Enter Password"required><br><br>
              Email<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"required><br><br>
              Phone No.<input type="text" name="phone-no" placeholder="Phone No"required><br><br>
              Gender<input type="text" name="gender" placeholder="Male or Female"required><br><br>
              State<input type="text" name="state" placeholder="State"required><br><br>
              <button type="submit" name="home">Home</button>
              <button type="submit" name="sub">Submit</button>
              <button type="submit" name="reset">Reset</button>
            </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','123456789','eedb');
if ($con)
{
    if (isset($_POST['sub']))
    {
        $n= $_POST['name'];
        $un=$_POST['username'];
        $p=$_POST['password'];
        $cp=$_POST['confirm-pass'];
        $e=$_POST['email'];
        $pn=$_POST['phone-no'];
        $g=$_POST['gender'];
        $s=$_POST['state'];
        mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `register`");
        $insert= mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `register`(`name`, `username`, `password`, `confirm-pass`, `email`, `phone-no`, `gender`, `state`) VALUES ('$n','$un','$p','$cp','$e','$pn','$g','$s')");
        if ($insert)
        {
            echo "<center>Data Successfully Submitted</center>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<center>Data Not Submitted</center>";
        }
    }
}
else
{
    echo "<center>Oh!no there is an error.<br><br>But don't worry we have an army of trained chimpanzies to deal with it.<br><br> <image src='images/chimps.jpg'><br><br>Come Back Soon</center>";
}
if (isset($_POST['home']))
{
    header("location:index.php");
}
if (isset($_POST['reset']))
{
    header("location:register.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: you have 1 too many `)` at the end of your insert query

Comment: still in problem nothing happened

Comment: remove `mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `register` ");` since that's not doing anything also echo out the insert query and directly paste it into the database and see if it throws any errors like a column name has been spelt wrong.

Comment: I've reopened the question since you deleted the extra `)`. You will need to post your HTML form in order to know if everything is correct in there. Otherwise, this is guesswork. We also don't know what you entering as data for the POST arrays and MySQL may be complaining about that, but you're not checking for errors via PHP and MySQL. So, do that.

Comment: i have tried to run queries separately and never got an error and even It actually enters the data in tables, but not from PHP. There are no spelling mistakes for column.i have also given screenshot of my DataBase just in case you want it

Comment: As Fred says in his answer, getting an error from the MySQLi driver is essential here - let the system tell you what is wrong! This is the first thing to fix.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't post your HTML form, I am posting the following answer, which is what your HTML form should (basically) look like, which btw only contains the one example element.

You will need to fill in the rest and follow the same convention.

```
<form method="post" action="handler.php">

First name:
<input type="text" name="name">
<br>
<input type="submit" name="sub" value="Submit">

</form>
```

Then escape your values, should there contain any characters that MySQL may complain about, such as apostrophes.

I.e.: `Doug's Bar & Grill`.

Then:

```
$n= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);
```

Something you should use or a prepared statement since your code is presently open to an SQL injection.

- Ref: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)

And do the same for all your other POST arrays.

The `name` attribute is required for POST arrays when using pure PHP and a post method for the HTML form.

Sidenote: Your entire code is dependant on the following conditional statement
`if (isset($_POST['sub'])){...}`. So make sure that that form element bears the same name attribute for it.

- **Check for errors also.**

Since this does not help you:

```
echo "<center>Data Not Submitted</center>";
```

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

It's unclear as to what you're trying to do with this line:

```
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `register` ");
```

If the goal is to check if a row exists, then consult one of my answers on Stack:

- [check if row exists with mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252904/check-if-row-exists-with-mysql/22253579#22253579)

---

**Passwords**

I also noticed that you may be storing passwords in plain text. This is not recommended.

Use one of the following:

- PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.
- Compatibility pack (if PHP < 5.5) https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/

**Important sidenote about column length:**

If and when you do decide to use `password_hash()` or the compatibility pack (if PHP < 5.5) https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/, it is important to note that if your present password column's length is anything lower than 60, it will need to be changed to that (or higher). The manual suggests a length of 255.

You will need to ALTER your column's length and start over with a new hash in order for it to take effect. Otherwise, MySQL will fail silently.

Other links of interest:

- [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471)
- [`crypt()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)
- [`bcrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt)
- [`scrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt)
- [**On OPENWALL**](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)
- [**PBKDF2**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)
- [**PBKDF2 on PHP.net**](http://php.net/hash-pbkdf2)
- [**PBKDF2 For PHP**](https://defuse.ca/php-pbkdf2.htm)

---

**HTML stickler:**

The `<center>` tag is deprecated and has been removed from Web standards.

For more information, visit the following:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
$insert= mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `register`(`name`, `username`, `password`, `confirm-pass`, `email`, `phone-no`, `gender`, `state`)VALUES ('$n','$un','$p','$cp','$e','$pn','$g','$s')");
```

you can try to use notepad++ or any other editor (e.g netbeans )that will make the open and closed brackets more obvious .