# The input are being duplicated

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having problem on duplication of data when updating in row of mysql.
I am changing bed of a user where I can get at table1 the field fname, which is the names of user. Then send to table2, then already get the fname using `rfname='$fname'`, This is my html getting a pop up that get the list of room by $roommedical. Iwant To not duplicate the entry. or how can i delete first the past row value before updating it to other row., The value on roommedical is default the only i want to change is rfname.

```
<label class="selectDrop" >Check This For Room:</label>
<input class="selectDrop" type="checkbox" name="statmed" value="active" id="statmed" />
<label class="selectDrop11" >Medical Ward:</label>
<input class="selectDrop11" type=text id=medbed name=roommedical value="<?php echo $roommedical?>" placeholder="Select Medical Bed">
<!--BUTTON--><input class="selectDrop11" type="button" name="choice" onClick="selectValue('medbed')" value="Check">
```

And This is my submit form php

```
$roommedical = clean($_POST['roommedical']);
$statmed = clean($_POST['statmed']);
mysql_query("UPDATE room SET rfname='$fname',statmed='$statmed' Where  roommedical='$roommedical'");
```

When updating the patient name is duplicating the the red box line is the example of duplicating of my entry This is the picture

[image]

Thank you. I am bad at this, I know. Please understand me.

Comment: alter your column so that it is unique

Comment: If you do not want records with duplicate values you need to set up a unique index for that column. Additionally, you should do validation *before* you attempt to insert that record.

Comment: or check in select if it exists first; many ways to do this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [check if row exists with mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252904/check-if-row-exists-with-mysql)

Comment: What is `first table` vs. `second table`? Your question only shows 1 table, `room`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the patient is moving to a different bed, you need to clear out the old bed before updating the new one. So do:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE room SET rfname='',statmed='None' Where  rfname='$fname'");
mysql_query("UPDATE room SET rfname='$fname',statmed='$statmed' Where  roommedical='$roommedical'");
```

BTW, in general it's preferable to use the `id` from the first table as the foreign key in the second table, not the name.