# Return a default value if no records are found

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this PHP code that selects one simple value:

```
$name = $mysqli->query('SELECT name FROM users WHERE id = ' . $id . ' LIMIT 1')->fetch_object()->name;
```

Now if the result is 0, it throws an error.

I want instead to return a default value like "No name" if there are no results.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What about `if ($result == null) return 'No Name'`; before you `fetch_object()`

Comment: Query first, check for result. If result return it, if not send your default.

Comment: `SELECT IFNULL(name, 'no name') FROM...`

Comment: You can also `mysqli_num_rows()` it's one way. If you want to keep your present method, then see the answer below.

Comment: @McNets that will still return null if there are no records in the table that match the condition.

Comment: @McNets although this seems as a good idea to get default value, if non present, it won't solve the error, where there is no data to return at all. it's not that the name field has no value, there is just no return.

Comment: However, your code stands to be open to an SQL injection, and all answers so far won't safeguard you against it. Use a prepared statement and check if the row exists while binding the result(s) as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252904/check-if-row-exists-with-mysql/22253579#22253579 and base yourself on that and with a ternary operator or `if/else`.

Answer (score 6):

Don't fetch the name directly, instead check, if there is data in it first. Something like this should work:

```
$result = $mysqli->query('SELECT name FROM users WHERE id = ' . $id . ' LIMIT 1')->fetch_object();

$name = (!$result) ? 'No name' : $result->name;
```

Additional, as [@RiggsFolly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2310830/riggsfolly) mentioned, it is suggested to use prepared statements, to reduce SQL possibilities:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name FROM users WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bind_param('i',$id);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_object();
```

Comment: [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Answer (score 3):

This can be done in pure SQL so that you wouldn't need any extra line of PHP code :

```
$name = $mysqli->query('SELECT IFNULL((SELECT name FROM users WHERE id = ' . $id . ' LIMIT 1), "No Name") name')->fetch_object()->name;
```

Comment: Upvoting for the SQL solution. Although I think this is better done at the application layer since it's much more clear what is happening (and that's coming from a database guy).

Comment: I agree with you, Dainis Abols's solution is what I would have done too. The reason for that is that I don't want the exact same behaviour for my app in the two cases of user found or user not found, while in this solution, if I have a user named "No Name" I have absolutely no way in the app level to determine if I am in the case of no user found or not. But sometimes that could be exactly what you want : having an app that acts the exact same in the two situations.

Comment: [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: @RiggsFolly : if my query is under a `if (is_numeric($id))` which seems to be the case since there are no quotes around `$id` I have absolutely nothing to fear. But thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, with prepared statement:

```
$result = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT name FROM users WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1');
$result->bind_param("i", $id);
$result->execute();
$result->bind_result($col1);
$result->fetch();
$name = (!$col1) ? 'No name' : $col1;
echo $name;
$result->close();
```