# How to use if/else statement in with SQL in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, if-statement

Actually I have the following code:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id, city, date_created FROM my_table WHERE city = :city ORDER BY date_created DESC LIMIT 1');
$stmt->execute(array(':city' => $city));
```

I try to explain what I want to do:

1. Check if there's a row containing `all` in column `city`.
2. If so, check if the date of this row in `date_created` ist newer that the date in the newest entry for the query above. If so, select this row, else select the newest entry of the query below.

I hope you understand what I want to do. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with if/else statements in SQL.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252904/check-if-row-exists-with-mysql/22253579#22253579 and look under *"Or a PDO method with a prepared statement:"* - most likely a duplicate of this question.

Comment: Step 1: Add `AND value = 'all'` to your where clause

Comment: ... or an `OR`, depending on what you want to look for.

Comment: However, seeing point #2; the question's too broad.

Comment: The answer you posted I feel it should be part of your question

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be simplified.

It looks like you should be able to just select rows where the city is either your parameter or 'all', order by `date_created` descending like you already are, and take the first row.

```
$sql = "SELECT id, city FROM news
        WHERE city IN(:city, 'all')
        ORDER BY date_created DESC LIMIT 1";
```

Since you know your query will only return one row, you can just use `fetch` instead of `fetchAll` to eliminate the unnecessary outer array.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(':city' => $city));
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 0):

Cause I'm not familiar with if/else statements in SQL but in PHP I made the following that's working:

```
<?php
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id, city, date_created FROM news WHERE city = :city ORDER BY date_created DESC LIMIT 1');
$stmt->execute(array(':city' => $city));
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach( $results as $row ) {
$date_city = $row['date_created'];
}
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id, city, date_created FROM my_table WHERE city = "all" ORDER BY date_created DESC LIMIT 1');
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach( $results as $row ) {
$date_all = $row['date_created'];
}
if ($date_all > $date_city) {
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id, city, date_created FROM my_table WHERE city = "all" ORDER BY date_created DESC LIMIT 1');
$stmt->execute(array(':city' => $city));
} else {
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id, city, date_created FROM my_table WHERE city = :city ORDER BY date_created DESC LIMIT 1');
$stmt->execute(array(':city' => $city));
}
?>
```

Comment: this statment `$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id, city FROM news WHERE city = "all" ORDER BY date_created DESC LIMIT 1');
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();` can be reduced to `$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT id, city FROM news WHERE city = "all" ORDER BY date_created DESC LIMIT 1')->fetchall();foreach($stmt as $row)`

Comment: It doesn't look like this should work, because `$row['date_created']` shouldn't be set, since you're only selecting id and city in your query.