# update record if certain value is exist in a specific column, otherwise insert a new one

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I took a look at many questions similar to mine, but I didn't get what I'm looking for, maybe you guys can help me

I have this table:

[image]

What I want to do is:

- Insert a new record (regardless whether "user_id" or "course_id" are already exist or not).
- BUT!, if there is a record with the same "user_id" and "course_id" and "tutorial_id", then just update "tutorial_id" and "tutorial2_id" and leave the rest as they are.

I don't want to declare column "tutorial_id" as UNIQUE, because more than a user can have the same "tutorial_id" (as you can see in the above picture).

In addition, ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE didn't work for me.

I'm thinking of using QUERY two times, one to select and check if record exist, and the other one whether to UPDATE or INSERT, but is that correct?

Comment: Show your `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` usage. You can make the pair of the three unique, so not just `tutorial_id` would be unqiue. e.g. `ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME 
add CONSTRAINT UQ_user_course_tut UNIQUE (user_id, course_id, tutorial_id)`

Comment: Then you need to create the unique key across those three columns and then the on duplicate key update will work.

Comment: *In addition, ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE didn't work for me.* why? What is your `PRIMARY KEY`. Are `user_id` AND `course_id` a unique combination?

Comment: *"I'm thinking of using QUERY two times, one to select and check if record exist, and the other one whether to UPDATE or INSERT, but is that correct?"* - See this Q&A then http://stackoverflow.com/q/22252904/1415724

Comment: Thank you guys, making three column unique is something new to me, it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ... syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). For it to work.

If your `user_id` and `course_id` combination is unique you could delete the `id` field from your table and make those two fields a primary key.

In any other case that the `id` field is also needed and makes a unique combination of the three for each record then make those three fields the primary key for you table (`id`,`user_id` and `course_id`).

Answer (score 0):

How about issuing the `UPDATE` first, and if no records are affected (using `row_count()` then `INSERT`? This way you only test the existence condition once.

[rextester demo](http://rextester.com/ZHDN45497)

```
update test set tutorial2_id = @tutorial2
where user_id = @user_id and course_id = @course_id and tutorial_id = @tutorial_id;

insert into test (user_id, course_id, tutorial_id, tutorial2_id)
select @user_id, @course_id, @tutorial_id, @tutorial2_id)
where row_count() = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, solved by making three columns as unique.