# INSERT IGNORE, LIMIT 1... how to check if row exists before INSERT, to make sure it's inserted only once

Tags: php, mysql

I've tried both of these, `INSERT IGNORE` and `LIMIT 1` but records continue to be inserted into my DB. Aren't these commands supposed to prevent a new row being inserted if the row exists already ? Is it because the auto_increment value is different when the new row is added and therefore it is technically a different row?

The relevant piece of code looks like this :

```
 $user_id = 3;
 while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            //this the the user_id in the user table of the matching phone number   
            echo $row['user_id']."<br />";
            //call this user_id contact_id
            $contact_id = $row['user_id'];
                $stmt2 = $con->prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO contacts (user_id, contact_id) VALUES(?,?)") or die(mysqli_error($con));
                $stmt2->bind_param('ii', $user_id, $contact_id) or die ("MySQLi-stmt binding failed ".$stmt2->error);
                $stmt2->execute() or die ("MySQLi-stmt execute failed ".$stmt2->error);

    }
```

I also tried :

```
$stmt2 = $con->prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO contacts (user_id, contact_id) VALUES(?,?) LIMIT 1")
```

My table structure looks something like this, 3 columns :

```
auto_inc     user_id     contact_id
   1            3           24
   2            3           12 
   3            3           87
etc...
```

Comment: Wouldn't a unique index on [user_id, contact_id] be a solution?

Comment: Quite simply yes.

Comment: *"Is it because the auto_increment value is different when the new row is added and therefore it is technically a different row?"* - Yep.

Comment: Either do what @Iceman suggested, or check to see if a record exists; query accordingly.

Comment: Have a look at this Q&A [check if row exists with mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22252904/1415724) it may be of help.

Comment: Or `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html may be more what you need.

Comment: @Fred-ii- So it looks like num_rows are the way to go.

Comment: @CHarris I would think so. I added another link, but if you want me to close the question as a duplicate, let me know. What Iceman said is also in that link I gave you.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes you can close the question if you think it's better for the SO Community that way.

Comment: sure thing @CHarris *cheers*