# Prepared statements isn't executing

Tags: php, mysqli

My php script for registrating using prepared statements isn't working and I can't figure out why.
Can somebody please check my code ? Thank you, and sorry for this post if it's duplicated but I can't figure it by myself

Code:

```
<?php

require_once 'connect.php';

$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$passwordR =  $_POST['confpassword'];

if ($password == $passwordR) {

$password = hash('sha512', $password); // použi password_hash
$prep_stmt = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email= ? ";
$stmt = connect()->prepare($prep_stmt);

if ($stmt) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();

    if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
        echo 0;
        die();

    } else {

        if ($insert_stmt = connect()->prepare("INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES ( ?  ,  ? )")) {
            $insert_stmt->bind_param('ss', $email, $password);
            $insert_stmt->execute();
            if (!$insert_stmt) {
                echo 2;
                echo mysqli_stmt_sqlstate($insert_stmt);
                die();
            } else {
                echo 1; //preslo to
                die();
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    echo 3; //db error
    die();
}
}
```

Comment: Don't use SHA for hashing passwords. Use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead.

Comment: @AlexHowansky thanks for advice :)

Comment: You don't need to use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` if you're binding parameters like you are, just pass the raw value.

Comment: `$insert_stmt->execute();
            if (!$insert_stmt->execute()) {` that is a problem.

Comment: you also don't need to use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` and shouldn't escape passwords once you use a safe hashing method.

Comment: `$stmt = connect()->` are you using a custom method?

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes - connect is method that returns $conn value, anyway my code worked before with real escape strings but I cant get it working right now with prepared statements

Comment: as I said earlier, your executes are an issue; you need to change that to `$insert_stmt->execute();
            if (!$insert_stmt) {` or without the `!`. --- `$insert_stmt->execute();
if ($insert_stmt) { echo "Success"; }`

Comment: you need to check for the real errors with `mysqli_error($Your_Conn)`.

Comment: you also didn't bind/fetch results before `num_rows`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- so how do I bind it? I thought that $stmt->store_result(); would store result

Comment: you can check out one of my answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/22253579/1415724

Comment: Does it echo anything?

Comment: if there is ! in if (!$insert_stmt) { it just act like it was successful and if not it just echo 2

Comment: @Fred-ii- well even from your previous answer I can't see whats wrong with it, I'm too much tired :D, I should definitely take a break

Comment: Taking a break and some sleep is a very good idea, take it from me. I've been there.

Comment: @Fred-ii- ty for your time, hope I'll solve it tomorrow

Comment: you're welcome, *cheers* - and take it slowly, one step at a time. Once you have one query going, then jump to the next, you'll get it.