# Why is this code to check duplicate usernames not executing properly?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

`$conn` properly connects to the  database.

The *users* table of the database consists of the following fields id,name, email, username and password. One of the entries in the table contains *benedict* as the value for the username.

**Code:**

```
$userslist = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=?");
$userslist->bind_param("s",$user);
$usersresult=$userslist->execute();
if($userslist->num_rows>0)
{
    $userErr="Username already exists";
    $errors++;
}
```

**Problem:**

When I enter a username(which is being stored in $user)  with *benedict* as the value, the code does not detect duplicate id in spite of already having such a username. Further, `$userslist->num_rows` when printed shows 0.

On the contrary the following code correctly identifies, that a duplicate id already exists and prints the errror. (this proves there is no connection error or table errors)

```
$query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$user."'";
    $qresult=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    if($qresult->num_rows>0)
    {   $userErr="Username already exists";
    $errors++;
    }
```

I am aware that unique key and PDO is a better solution. But why it doesn't prints proper results while using prepared statements.

Comment: affected rows has meaning for update- insert- delete queries. Should you not need found_rows or something a like?  edit: num_rows it is

Comment: Try to use- `rowCount` instead of affected_rows

Comment: can you output the value of $user? affected_rows should act like num_rows in a SELECT statement. What result do you get if you remove the WHERE clause from your statement?

Comment: echo $user prints the entered text in username field correctly. When I enter benedict it prints benedict. I tried changing affected_rows to num_rows. Still errors is not being displayed. When I remove the where clause and bin_param placeholder also, it does not print the error.

Comment: Sorry i meant what affected_rows result do you get without the where clause?

Comment: Prints -1 even after removing where clause and bin_param placeholders.

Comment: Have you tried printing the error as stated in my answer?

Comment: Nothing is being printed

Comment: savest way would be, to make the username having an unique constraint. When inserting a duplicate name, the query will fail and return an error. Let your php code intercept this error number and give the same "already exsits error" you generate now. That way it is sure no one inserts that name just between the check and the actual insert

Comment: @IvoP How to do that using mysqli instead of PDO?

Comment: that would be apart from the query to start: make the column Username unique using a tool like phpmyadmin or whatever you use to maintain/setup your database.

then check if errno == 1062. if so: the query failed because of duplicate
i will edit my answer below

Comment: Okay. Kindly help. :)

Comment: $query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$user."'";
 $qresult=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
 if($qresult->num_rows>0)
 { $userErr="Username already exists";
 $errors++;
 } This is correctly pointing out that the username already exists but prepared statement does not shows the error

Comment: See the updated question please

Answer (score 1):

An affected rows result of: **-1** indicates the query returned an error and therefore wasnt executed.

Check your query for errors in column/tables names etc.

Is your connection working?

Please try the following to debug:

```
$userslist = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=?");
$userslist->bind_param("s",$user);
$usersresult=$userslist->execute();
print_r($conn->error);
```

Answer (score 0):

Id suggest using PDO to start with, it is much safer for DB queries. http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php . I would also suggest that you use a count for this and not a SELECT *. This is a wasteful check to see if a row exists, it will be more efficient by using a count.

You would do this using PDO like this.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT count(1) FROM users WHERE username=?");
$stmt->execute(array($user));
$result = $stmt->fetch();
if($result)
{
if($result[0] == 1) echo "Username already taken";
else "username free";
}
else
{
echo "error";
}
```

Comment: I get that PDO is better but why the code in the question does not work? If I dont use preapred statements it works. $query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$user."'"; $qresult=mysqli_query($conn,$query); if($qresult->num_rows>0) { $userErr="Username already exists"; $errors++; } This is correctly pointing out that the username already exists but prepared statement does not shows the error.

Answer (score 0):

So error is not affected row: check why the query failed:

```
`
 <?php
 $userslist = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=?");
 $userslist->bind_param("s",$user);
 $usersresult=$userslist->execute();



 if($userslist->num_rows>0)
 {
     $userErr="Username already exists";
     $errors++;
 }
 elseif($userlist->affected_rows == -1) {

   echo 'An error occurred: ' . $conn->error;
 }
```

?>
`
but you do realise, in the few milliseconds between the check and an actual insert, there might be an other user inserting that exact same name?

Added: how to do it when username is unique indexed:

```
<?php
 $userslist = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, name, etc) VALUES (?,?, ?)");
 $userslist->bind_param("sss",$user, $name, $etc);
 $usersresult=$userslist->execute();

 if($conn->errno == 1062) {
     $userErr="Username already exists";
     $errors++;
 }
 elseif($conn->errno) {
   echo 'An error occurred: ' . $conn->error;
 }
 else {
    if($userlist->affected_rows == 1) {
       echo 'success';
    } 
    else {
        echo 'unknown why not inserted';
    }
 }


?>
```

Comment: As stated affected_rows acts like num_rows in a SELECT statement. this is not the problem. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

Comment: Doesn't show the error still even after executing the mentioned code.

Comment: run the error call on the $conn object as indicated in my answer

Comment: $query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$user."'"; $qresult=mysqli_query($conn,$query); if($qresult->num_rows>0) { $userErr="Username already exists"; $errors++; } This is correctly pointing out that the username already exists but prepared statement does not shows the error

Comment: error is something else then "i found this user already". Error is like "the table is corrupted, column does not exsist " etc

Comment: @IvoP When the username is unique indexed and if I use the above code, I get this error: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'Duplicate entry 'benedict' for key 'username' It doesn't even enter the first if condition

Comment: put a try-catch around the execute() line

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($userslist) > 0){

    echo "username already exists"
}
```

[check if row exists with mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252904/check-if-row-exists-with-mysql) - similiar question

Comment: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost","user","password","db");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users where username='".$_POST['username']."'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$count = $result->num_rows;
if($count > 0)
{
echo "Username ".$_POST['username']." already exists!";
}
```