# Unknown prepared statement handler given to mysqld_stmt_execute

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement, netscaler

Having an issue with prepared statement where no results are returned. Upon examining MySql's general query log, I can see where the connection is being made, but there never appears to be a query executed.

After adding `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL)`, the following error message is returned:

```
Unknown prepared statement handler (4) given to mysqld_stmt_execute
```

The following is the code executing the prepared statement:

```
$something_in = 'a-string-of-text';

if($stmt = $this->prepare("SELECT first, last, phone FROM people WHERE something=? ORDER BY last ASC")){

   try{

       if (!$stmt->bind_param('s', $something_in)) {
          die('bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
        } 

       $stmt->execute();
       $stmt->bind_result($first, $last, $something, $phone);

       while($stmt->fetch()){

           $returnArray[] = array(
               'first_name'    => $first,
               'last_name'     => $last,
               'something'     => $something,
               'phone'         => $phone
           );

       }

       $stmt->free_result();
       $stmt->close();

       return $returnArray; // we make it to here with a blank array instead of expected results

   } catch (Exception $ex) {

       return $ex->getMessage();

   }

}
```

Has anyone else run into this issue? It seems rather odd.

MySQL Version: 5.6

PHP Version: 7

Also another useful piece of information would be that we're using netscaler which acts as a proxy between our app servers and database servers. I'm inclined to believe this might be where the hangup is happening.

**EDIT**

Confirmed this is in relation to our netscaler proxy as connecting app server directly to db server resolves the issue. Will post solution once cause determined.

Comment: Try checking for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) along the way.

Comment: Might want `store_result()` in there [as I had pointed out to me the other day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49197768/session-destroyed-after-page-reload)

Comment: A lot of problems can be detected and resolved by [enabling exceptions in `mysqli`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578243/turning-query-errors-to-exceptions-in-mysqli) so mistakes aren't easily ignored.

Comment: Updated question with results obtained after enabling exceptions in mysqli.

Answer (score 0):

A solution for this particular edge case has not yet been identified. However moving away from `mysqli` and using php's `PDO` library has resolved the dilemma for the short term.