# Having a problem with prepared number of rows statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, xampp, prepared-statement

I have been working on a site in PHP and SQL. In my last question some one pointed out to me that I should be using prepared statements in order to protect my site against SQL injections. I have been going through my site changing all my queries to prepared statements, however I am having a problem with checking if a username exist in the database when a user signs up.

Here is the code that I have tried, it does not produce any errors, however it allows users to sign up with usernames that are already in my users table.

```php
$uname = $_POST['uname'];
$stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username= ?");

   /* Bind parameters, s - string, b - blob, i - int, etc */
   $stmt -> bind_param("s", $uname);
   $stmt -> execute();

   /* Fetch the value */
   $stmt -> fetch();
   $numberofrows = $stmt->num_rows;

   /* Close statement */
   $stmt -> close();

if($numberofrows>0) {
   echo "Username Already Exist";
} else {
//rest of my code
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You closed your connection too fast.

Comment: You also need to store results.  [See this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22252904/1415724) here on Stack. It shows you how to use it completely.

Comment: If you don't need more data, only the number of rows, it's better to use `select count(*)` than `select * `

Comment: Funky Forty Niner Thank you! Is there any way to accept a comment as an answer, and should I put my new code as a answer for other people?

Comment: Felippe Duarte I don't understand, should I not use a prepared statement for this? I'm still learning so if you could provide why or why not so I know in the future..

Comment: @AndrewSturgis19 welcome. Btw, you need to use `@member_name` to ping directly. It is a duplicate of it then. I'll just close it as a duplicate :)

Comment: Sounds good @FunkFortyNiner :)

Comment: use `count(*)` as suggested by @FelippeDuarte, or if we don't need a count, and we just need to check for existence of a matching row, then we can just do `SELECT username FROM users WHERE username= ? LIMIT 1`, then do the one `fetch` (like in the existing code), and just check if fetch returned a row or not.  We see `num_rows` used so many times where its not needed, and there's some variety of behavior with `num_rows`, some of the behavior is unexpected.  bottomline: do not use `num_rows`, do a fetch (either of COUNT(*), and test the value returned) or check the fetch of a single row,